# How to Pass Error Code with Message in RestEasy

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I am using the following code to send Error message.

This is my own error code and custom message. I am sending the message in response.

```
throw new WebApplicationException(
    Response.status(1002)
            .header(ae.getMessage(), ae)
            .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .build());
```

The problem is, the front end guys are able to see the status code but not the message. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should use entity method to set message:

```
Response.status(1002)
        .entity(ae.getMessage())
        .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        .build());
```